# FlutterFire - Where to get verification code # through email on FirebaseAuth

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

im new on using FIrebase
With major update, FlutterFire added new methods

```
NEW: Added support for applyActionCode().  
NEW: Added support for checkActionCode().  
NEW: Added support for verifyPasswordResetCode().
```

And on documentation https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage/

```
User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
if (!user.emailVerified) {
   await user.sendEmailVerification();
}

//Firebase will send an automated email to the user with a unique code. 
//This code can then be entered via the applyActionCode() method. 
//You can first check whether the code is valid by using the checkActionCode() method:
```

**await user.sendEmailVerification();** this only sends verification links to user email to verify. Not a verification CODE.

What should i do to receive that code through email? So I can use the method **verifyPasswordResetCode().**. Thanks

Comment: Hi, did you find an answer for your final question (verifyPasswordResetCode)?

Comment: These methods are in the FirebaseAuth instance.